# C# Strings and Arrays

Tags: c#

so I was experimenting with the Split method and I encountered an issue and consised it into the following:

```
String strvalues1 = "";
String[] splitter1 = strvalues1.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(splitter1[0]);
Console.WriteLine(splitter1);
```

So when I run this I DO NOT get an error.
What does it print if there is nothing in the strvalues1?

Comment: It doesn't find the split character, so it just returns the string. What exactly were you expecting it to return?

Comment: Were you expecting to get an empty array?  Split will always return at least one element, regardless of whether or not the delimiter is present in the string.

Comment: [String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0) states: _The Split method ignores any element of separator whose value is null or the empty string ("")_

Comment: Incidentally `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will give you a zero length array

Comment: Also, an array cannot be printed directly. `Console.WriteLine(splitter1);` will just print the type name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Split` is to split a string to an array by a separator. In your case, it's trying to split an empty string `""` (`strvalues1`) with a character of space `' '`. It will run like this

1. Put the first found string (it's empty `""`) into your new array (`splitter1`)
2. Find your separator `" "` (if not found, break the loop)
3. Print your array with only 1 item which is `""` (`splitter1[0]`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I can see that it prints something, I assume it is a space, but why?

Comment: I was just wondering(sorry if this is too stupid) , so I print this ""  and I can see that It prints something, I assume It is a space, or is it?

Comment: It has no space, you can verify it with `Console.WriteLine(splitter1[0].Length);`, the result is 0 which means it's an empty string. You also can try to add `String strvalues1 = "a";` for value verification again @EricMovsessian

Comment: Thank you, to be honest the reason why I asked the question is because I was doing this:

String strvalues = "6f,   2D,5C,2d";
            
            String[] splitter = strvalues.Split(' ');
This makes an array with the following characters
{6f,}     {(space)}    {(space)}       {2D,5C,2d}

I kind of understand why, but still why does this happen like this?

Comment: I tried your value here https://dotnetfiddle.net/JdI9Rm, but I got the length of that array is 2 which are `6f,` and `2D,5C,2d`. One possibility is that you have some special characters in your value.

Comment: Thank you but It is actually like this

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3L5sIV

Comment: `Every instance of a separator character produces a value in the returned array. Consecutive separator characters produce the empty string as a value in the returned array. You can see how an empty string is created in the following example, which uses the space character as a separator.`  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split). It means after found separator, the next character will be add to the list (even though it's another separator)